# Problems with Embedded Functions within Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I'm trying to simulate a very simple model using an embedded matlab function that takes the input and add's 10 to the value using a constant block that inputs into the matlab function, which then outputs to a display block.

As soon as I press simulate I get an abundance of errors.  First I get a huge paragraph in orange text stating a warning out the solver `'variableStepDiscrete'` instead of solver `'ode45'`

Here is the remaining lines that are echo'd from the command prompt:

```
Code Directory :
 "/Users/dazgti/Documents/MATLAB/slprj/_sfprj/embeddedFunction/_self/sfun/src"

Machine (#32): "embeddedFunction"  Target : "sfun"


Chart "MATLAB Function" (#49):

.
     "c2_embeddedFunction.h"
 "c2_embeddedFunction.c"

 "embeddedFunction_sfun.h"

 "embeddedFunction_sfun.c"

 "embeddedFunction_sfun_debug_macros.h"


Interface and Support files:

 "embeddedFunction_sfun_registry.c"

Code generation failed Attempt to execute SCRIPT union as a function:
/Users/dazgti/Documents/MATLAB/union.m
```

I have a script file within my matlab directory called `union.m`, but I have no idea why its mentioning it.

[image: sim]

```
function y  = fcn(u)
%#codegen

x = u + 10;

y = x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB Function block works by generating "C" code for the MATLAB code you entered in the block. In the process of generating code there could have been a call to union function in MATLAB from MATLAB Function block infrastructure. Since you have overridden the union function instead of the built-in function MATLAB might have attempted to call your script which caused the error. It is better to avoid naming your functions same as MATLAB built-in functions.

Comment: Thanks.  I've changed the function name to `hello(u)` and still the problem persists.  I have not used my `union.m` script for a long time so I have no idea why its trying to find it.  This is the first time I've tried to embed a function within simulink.

Comment: The only solution is to take out the `union.m` from the MatLab path which seems absurd to me.  I also had another problem when initially removing the `union.m` file regarding MatLab not finding the C compiler that ships with XCode.  This is now resolved except the initial problem with the `union.m` file.

Comment: MATLAB functions in current directory and then the ones in the path you added take precedence over the built-in ones. In MATLAB can you do "which -all union" and see what it returns? It should contain only built-in or under your MATLAB installation.

Comment: Thanks, I've typed in the command `which all union` and its returned this:  `built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a_Student.app/toolbox/matlab/ops/@char/all)  % char method`  Do you mean that I have possibly named my own custom custom M file `union.m` the same as a built in function?

Comment: Rename your `union.m` to something like `my_union.m`. Close and restart MATLAB. The warnings about the solver you can ignore, it's telling you it changed the solver from `ode45` (the default) to `VariableStepDiscrete` because you don't have any continuous states in your model.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes I've renamed it to union4.m and everything is working fine now.  I fully understand the original answer now, as in renaming the `union.m` file.  I thought `Naven` meant rename the embedded function.  The irony is that the `union.m` eminated from an official MatLab tutorial!